# Segmentation Fault using strcmp in C?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I was getting Segmentation Fault (core dump) error when I run the code. After using some printf statement I found out that there is an error in strcmp part, maybe it's because comparing a char with a string? How do I fix this?

```
// this function checks if the file contains the *string

bool checkIfMatch(char *string, FILE *file) {

    while (true) {

        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file);
        if (buff == NULL)
            break;

        char *substring=strstr(buff, string);
        if ((strcmp(buff, substring)) == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

Comment: use strncmp() instead of strcmp() i.e strlen(substring).

Comment: This: `if(buff ==NULL) break;` will *never* cause a break; Use `if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) == NULL) break;` You also never check the results of your `strstr` before using them in `strcmp`.

Comment: and `strcmp` and `strstr` is enough only one or the other of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You have no guarantee that `substring` is non-NULL. So you need to test it:

```
bool checkIfMatch(char *string, FILE *file) {
    char buff[1024];
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file)) {
        char *substring=strstr(buff, string);
        if (substring && !strcmp(buff, substring)) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Other problems:

- In your code `if (buff == NULL) break;` will *never* cause a break. You need to test the return value of `fgets`. (See WhozCraig's comment)
- `fgets` keeps the carriage-return, which is probably not what you want.
- The strstr/strcmp is confused: you probably just want `strcmp`, or maybe just `strstr`.
- If the file has a line longer than 1022 characters, then you might miss finding the string.

Comment: +1 (was waiting for the CRLF detection). And I agree with the `strstr`/`strcmp` confusion, I *think* `strncmp` would do what the OP is going for but hard saying.

Answer (score 0):

The array `buff` is not null terminated. You need to do that for the `str...` family of functions

PS: Learn to indent the code
PPS: Use a debugger to find of the value of `buff`

Answer (score 0):

if the `buff` is not `NULL` terminated, then problem will come in the `strcmp`.  In your case, initialize the `buff` variable(to zero) at the declaration part. Otherwise check the `filesize` and then add `NULL` character at the `buff`:

```
[filesize+1]='\0'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *substring=strstr(buff, string);
    if ((strcmp(buff, substring)) == 0)
        return true;
```

`char *substring` in the case where you have a match, `substring` is pointing to somewhere inside buf if no match `substring` is pointing to `NULL`, and when you do `strcmp(buff,substring)` this will never be zero.